# Почему событие onclick вызывает перезагрузку страницы?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться.
Есть пара кнопок, которые добавляют в текстовое поле теги типа `[code][/code]` и `[blockquote][/blockquote]`. После нажатия на кнопку теги появляются и тут же происходит перезагрузка страницы - теги исчезают(

Пример кода:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value='[code][/code]'" value = "Добавить код" />
  <textarea cols="60"  rows="7" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

P.S. Извините за дублирование вопроса

Comment: Потому что после вставки кода идёт запрос на форму. Допишите `return false` после 
    value='[code][/code]'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В событии onclick нужно вернуть false. Вот так:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('text').value='[code][/code]'; return false;"
```

Если нужно дополнить существующий текст, и ещё и позицию каретки выставлять, то лично мне удобнее написать отдельную функцию:

```
function onSomeClick(typeInsert) { // функция добавляет необходимый тэг в textarea
  var txt = document.getElementById('text');
  var tag, caretpos=0;
  switch(typeInsert) { 
    case 'code':
      tag = '[code][/code]';
      caretpos = 8;
      break;
    case 'bq':
      tag = '[blockquote][/blockquote]';
      caretpos = 14;
      break;
  }
  txt.value += tag;
  setCaretPosition(txt, txt.value.length-caretpos) //устанавливаем позицию каретки
  return false;

}

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) { //функция устанавливает позицию каретки в указанное место
if(elem != null) {
    if(elem.createTextRange) {
        var range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.move('character', caretPos);
        range.select();
    }
    else {
        if(elem.selectionStart) {
            elem.focus();
            elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
        }
        else
            elem.focus();
    }
}
```

}

У моего варианта есть 1 минус: нельзя вставить код в любое место в тексте. Но, разобравшись как работает функция setCaretPosition и как можно получить положение каретки в textarea, агрейднуть мою функцию Вам не составит труда.
P.S. В коде возможны очепятки, надеюсь всё верно работает.

Comment: Спасибо:) А как сделать, чтобы теги не затирали уже введенный текст и еще чтобы курсор оказался между тегами - [code]|[/code]

Comment: А можно сделать так:
pos = s.lastIndexOf('][');
а потом вызвать setCaretPosition, подставив вместо caretPos - pos+1.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло:)